# Is it possible to see user journey of a userId?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I set the userId for my users and I saw this parameter in debug console for my test devices. but users do not have this field in their user journey

Thanks

Comment: the nature of this question is fairly product specific. flurry is not itself a tool for programmers and programming; where as integrating the product would be on-topic, this question seems to be invoking flurry customer support specialist, or a product owner\manager\director... those are not roles in this community even if some of those individuals are a part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, at this time User Journeys do not show user IDs.

Comment: Do you plan on allowing us to see user journeys for a specific user id in the future? I've found it's very difficult to find opportunities to carry over user id's to marry information with internal systems